# convert a complex structure to byte array in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, struct, byte

This is my structs' definition

```
    public struct SPMSifHdr
    {
        public UInt32 ui32Synch1;
        public UInt32 ui32Synch2;
        public ushort ui16Version;
        public UInt32 ui32Cmd;
        public UInt32 ui32BodySize;
    };

    struct SPMSifReturnKcdLclMsg
    {
        public SPMSifHdr hdr1;
        public char ff;
        public char[] Dta;
        public bool Debug;
        public char[] szOpId;
        public char[] szOpFirst;
        public char[] szOpLast;
    }
```

How to convert struct `SPMSifReturnKcdLclMsg` to array of bytes to send via tcp/ip?
Forgive my language, I can't use english very well :p

Comment: Once the byte-converted struct comes to the other side of the TCP/IP channel, how do you want to convert it back ? Do both sides share the dll containing the struct definition ?

Comment: i just make the client program. the program should send the formatted data to an interface

Comment: So the tcp listener needs a way to understand the bytes. If you use the binary serialization the other side needs the assembly containing the struct definitions to be able to deserialize it.

Comment: @YkmLo, I would recommend XML Serialization or JSON serialization over binary serialization. You also need to consider version-ing your data-structures and/or serialization logic if there is possibility of server serving different version on clients!

Comment: @YkmLo: I agree with VinayC. You could also use protobuf serialization that is very small and fast.

Comment: using binary serialization, the program works fine. the problem is that the server doesn't respond back. the truth is i just convert someone else's c++ code into c#. maybe i'm sending the wrong message to the server. anyway, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Socket socket = OpenSocket();
using (var stream = new NetworkStream(socket))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, obj); 
}
```

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that your structs should be marked as Serializable

Comment: Do the structs need to be marked as `Serializable` for this to work?

Comment: @YkmLo: Just put `[Serializable]` attribute over the two struct definitions.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using binary formatter for byte conversion - its .NET proprietary serialization. Unless the code at receiving end is also .NET, you are probably rely on serialization format out-side your control. Even if the receiving part is .NET code then also one may need to add some kind of versioning logic...